# How to disable Flutter form submission until valid phone number entered when using IntlPhoneField package?

Tags: flutter, forms

Below is my IntlPhoneField widget's code.I want to disable the submit button of the form until the user enters a valid phone number. How can I do it with this IntlPhoneField package? package link : https://pub.dev/packages/intl_phone_field

```
IntlPhoneField(
                 invalidNumberMessage: 'Enter Valid Phone Number',
                 flagsButtonPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                 disableLengthCheck: false,
                 dropdownIconPosition: IconPosition.trailing,
                 dropdownTextStyle: TextStyle(
                     fontSize: 14,
                     color: Colors.black,
                     fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                 style: TextStyle(
                     fontSize: 14,
                     color: primaryColor,
                     fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                 decoration: InputDecoration(
                   // errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
                   border: OutlineInputBorder(
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)),
                     borderSide: BorderSide(color: primaryColor),
                   ),
                   enabledBorder:  OutlineInputBorder(
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                     borderSide: BorderSide(color: placeholderColor),
                   ),
                   focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                     borderSide: BorderSide(color: placeholderColor),
                   ),
                   focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                       borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1,color: errorColor)
                   ),
                   filled: true,
                   fillColor: placeholderColor,
                   contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15,left: 15),
                   // border: InputBorder.none,
                   hintText: "Type here…".i18n,
                   hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey),
                 ),
                 initialCountryCode: 'SE',
                 onChanged: (contactNo) {
                   setState(() {
                     this.contactNo = contactNo.toString();
                   });
                 },
               ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `validator` on `IntlPhoneField`. A  `FocusNode` or inside `validator`/ `onChanged` can be used to update the UI.

```dart
 var contactNo;

  bool _isValidPhoneNum = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          IntlPhoneField(
            showCountryFlag: false,
            invalidNumberMessage: 'Enter Valid Phone Number',
            flagsButtonPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            validator: (p0) {
              print(p0?.completeNumber.toString());
              if (p0 != null &&
                  p0.completeNumber.toString() != "+11111111111") {
                _isValidPhoneNum = false;
                return "Enter Valid number";
              }
              _isValidPhoneNum = true;
              return null;
            },
            dropdownTextStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Type here…",
              hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            onChanged: (contactNo) {
              setState(() {
                this.contactNo = contactNo.toString();
              });
            },
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _isValidPhoneNum ? () {} : null, child: Text("Submit"))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why I can't use a solution like this is when it comes to different countries the length of a phone number changes.

Comment: phone number length depends on country, are you pointing just country base number verification?

Comment: yes. I want to validate numbers based on countries